# SQL 'float' data type, when output as XML, causes undesired float result

Tags: sql-server, xml, floating-point

You can try simply:
table1: has a column1 of type 'float' 
instead of

`SELECT column1 from Table1;` gives values as seen in table.

Say this returns 15.1

However, if you try

```
Select column1 from Table1 
FOR XML PATH('Table1'), Root('SomeRoot'), TYPE
```

returns: 1.510000000000000e+001

Has anyone seen this, and how was this fixed?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

Comment: Dana: This isn't a duplicate. The OP has a problem with formatting, not representation.

Comment: @JW, I assume this is sql server 2005+ because of the 'for xml path' syntax, but OP if I am wrong let me know.  My answer wont work for other db's more than likely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you get when you work with floating point numbers.  You can try this though:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(column1 AS decimal(38,2)))
```

you will just need to adjust the precision on the decimal to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I was using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2):

Also assuming MSSQL, the `str` function might fit your needs ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)):

```
select str(column1, 3,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to convert the float value into a string to solve this problem.
Just convert the float value into a `decimal` or a `numeric` type, with the precision you want.

```
SELECT CAST(column1 AS decimal(38,2))
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(column1 AS numeric(18,5))
```

When then number will be parsed in XML by Sql Server, it won't be in an exponential form.

This approach is obviously faster than a string conversion (that would occur twice).