# SUM() function showing exponential value in XML in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL code where the output is required in XML format that is going to be saved on a text file as XML. But the problem is when I am trying to use `SUM()` over a column the output in `XML` is showing an exponential value. How to get the actual sum in XML? If the sum is 0 then it should show 0 but it is showing as `0.000000000000000e+000` value in XML.

I have tried using Convert function in SQL but is of no help.

```
SELECT  tbl.A,
            sum(tbl.B)
    FROM (
            SELECT A,
           CASE
                WHEN C = 1
                THEN D
                ELSE 0
           END AS B
            FROM table1
        ) tbl
    GROUP BY tbl.A
    FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS;
```

Expected result should show the actual sum in XML and not the exponential value.

Comment: SUM shouldn't be showing exponents of anything. You mention that you want the count but you aren't using the COUNT aggregate function.

Comment: Hi, I am using SUM in my query and it is showing me an exponential value. I changed my statement to sum and not count. Thank you for that.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to use a subquery here. You can just put table1 directly in your from clause.

Comment: I am sorry. I modified my query. Can you help now?

Comment: So you don't like the displayed value? Because 0.0000000 is exactly the same as 0. What is the datatype of column D in table1?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190260/sql-float-data-type-when-output-as-xml-causes-undesired-float-result

Answer (score 0):

You use function Cast or convert for field D.

Example:

```
SELECT  A,sum( CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN CAST( D AS DECIMAL(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as S
FROM table1
GROUP BY A
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS;
```